# jquery: flot chart - pan: how to do something on Dragstart

Tags: jquery, mouseevent, flot

I am using flot chart with pan (navigate js) option

```
<script src="{% static 'js/plugins/flot/jquery.flot.js' %}"></script>
<script src="{% static 'js/plugins/flot/jquery.flot.tooltip.min.js' %}"></script>
<script src="{% static 'js/plugins/flot/jquery.flot.resize.js' %}"></script>
<script src="{% static 'js/plugins/flot/jquery.flot.navigate.js' %}"></script>
```

Now when i start draging the chart i want to do something. How to do it.

I tried:

```
$(document).on("dragstart", ".flot-overlay", function(){
   alert("testing")
});
```

checked in the dom:

[image]

but its not working

Comment: Have you tried binding the event on `".flot-base"` instead of on `".flot-overlay"`? From the documentation, Hooks section: Currently, eventHolder actually contains both the static canvas used for the plot itself and the overlay canvas used for interactive features because some versions of IE get the stacking order wrong. The hook only gets one event, though (either for the overlay or for the static canvas).

Comment: Ok I will check that